# kubernetes-maven-plugin - Dockerfile Build Fails with .git issue

Tags: java, maven, dockerfile, fabric8, jkube

I am testing out some migration in Maven from a Spotify dockerfile plugin with Fabric8 to just using Eclipse's JKube plugin. I have been hitting errors with what I thought would be a simple enough build using a Dockerfile.

The POM config is like so:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jkube</groupId>
                <artifactId>kubernetes-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <name>${docker.image.prefix}/${docker.image.name}</name>
                            <build>
                                <dockerFile>${project.basedir}/Dockerfile</dockerFile>
                            </build>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

The Dockerfile is (per config above) in the root of the project. It is very simple

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9:x86_64-ubi-jre-11.0.12_7_openj9-0.27.0
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD target/${JAR_FILE} microservice.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "microservice.jar"]
```

Running `mvn clean install k8s:build` ends with the following error message:

```
[INFO] --- kubernetes-maven-plugin:1.5.1:build (default-cli) @ persistence-svc ---
[INFO] k8s: Running in Kubernetes mode
[INFO] k8s: Building Docker image in Kubernetes mode
[ERROR] k8s: Failed to execute the build [Error while trying to build the image:<PROJ>\target\docker\<PREFIX>\<IMAGE>\build\maven\.git\objects\pack\pack-c35818936460f0bb0c1b903466f7bf1a17f22cc8.idx]
```

I am not sure what I am missing. I tried to add a jKube ignore file but that made no difference.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I was on the correct track with the ignore file.
The syntax I had was incorrect. I had just `.git/` and needed `.git/**`.

```
.git/**
src/**
target/classes/**
target/persistence-svc.jar
target/persistence-svc-sources.jar
```

It seems a little crazy that this should cause problems. Anyways I am sure there is a nicer solution overall but this gets me going without changing anything other than the plugins.

**EDIT**:
Indeed there is a better way for my use-case. Use `.jkube-dockerinclude` instead. Example [here](https://www.eclipse.org/jkube/docs/kubernetes-maven-plugin#ex-build-dockerinclude).

Comment: Yes, the .jkube-xxx files have a specific syntax `Wildcards are also supported, patterns will be matched using FileSystem#getPathMatcher glob syntax.`
It's nice to hear that you were able to switch from one plugin to another with very little hassle. \o/